# convert default index to hashed mongodb

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I'd like to make sharding of my existing users collection. Users collection has already single ascending index by default  `{"_id" : 1}`. I want to convert this index to "hashed" and to shard based on this hashed key according to the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/shard-collection-with-a-hashed-shard-key/):

I've tried "brute-force" solution to delete default index and then recreate it with "hashed" parameter but it doesn't allow to do that.

**UPDATE:** I've also tried db.users.ensureIndex({_id: "hashed"}). But after I run this command nothing  really happens.

```
switched to db bg_shard_single
mongos> db.users.ensureIndex({_id:"hashed"});
mongos> db.users.getIndexes();
[
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                },
                "ns" : "bg_shard_single.users",
                "name" : "_id_"
        }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not allow you to do so because you can not create an index from `_id` field. Instead of this you can do something like this `db.collection.ensureIndex( { _id: "hashed" } )` to create a hashing index on this field.

Then you will see `"name" : "_id_hashed"` as your hashed index which you can use for sharding purposes later.

Answer (score 1):

I've found what was the problem. Apparently, I was using the old version of mongodb. That's why mongos didn't want me to update '_id' to "hashed". After I've updated to 2.4.8 as @Salvador-Dali mentions it becomes "name" : "_id_hashed".